# Why can't I combine commits into one?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit

Ok. I am at my wits end trying to find out why I can't merge two commits into one. Git is horribly complicated. I have series of commits that looks like this locally and remotely:

```
commit 6abb264c06b06d42ea7e07a469107b9d3d72dffa
Author: XXXX <xxx@xxxx.xxx>
Date:   Thu Jan 23 15:59:03 2014 -0500

   First Check-in again (forgot to add project file and forgot to tick off append to last commit)


commit 90b2468f5267a471d52f2d7cc7cb1cd8604b3b86
Author: XXXX <xxx@xxxx.xxx>
Date:   Wed Jan 22 22:57:20 2014 -0500

   First check-in
```

I want to combine them together into to look like this:

```
commit 90b2468f5267a471d52f2d7cc7cb1cd8604b3b86
Author: XXXX <xxx@xxxx.xxx>
Date:   Wed Jan 22 22:57:20 2014 -0500

   First check-in
```

I tried to rebase using pick, squash and whatever gourd named command available to no avail. It tells me it has squash/merged/picked whatever, but I always see two commits instead of one.

Also couldn't figure out what the difference was between pick and squash.  Also, I can't tell what the difference is between a commit and a branch. Moreover, I read that a branch is just a commit, but why do we have to merge branches but pick/squash (??) commits?  This is terribly confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're tripping over a bunch of minor irritations I have with git, all at the same time.  This is actually a good sign. :-)

First, rebase has problems with "rebasing" a root commit.  In reasonably modern versions you can do this with `git rebase -i --root`, which will let you squash or fixup the second commit into the first (root) commit.  You need that `--root` argument.  (Older versions of git lack `--root` and make this substantially more difficult.)

Next:

> what the difference was between pick and squash

In an interactive rebase, `pick` means "take the commit as is", and `squash` means "add this commit atop the previous commit".  There's no fundamental difference between `squash` and `fixup` except that the former gives you a chance to edit the commit message, and the latter just takes the "fixup" as a tree change (throwing away the commit message text entirely).

> what the difference is between a commit and a branch

A commit is an actual object inside the repository.  "A branch" is an ambiguous term, which sometimes means "a branch label"—which is just a reference to a commit, or equivalently, a name for a single commit—and sometimes means the data structure formed by a *series* of commits with their parentage.

It's been said that "git makes more sense when you understand *X*", for many different values of *X*.  This generalizes to "git makes much more sense once you understand git." :-)  Which actually is true in more than just the tautological sense, but is not much help in getting you there!  Fortunately [this web series](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/git-makes-more-sense-when-you-understand-x.html) is very helpful (in my opinion).  Read through it all, and the way that "branch" is ambiguous, but usually obvious which one someone means, will probably make more sense.

---

Edit: example session:

```
$ cd /tmp/trepo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/trepo/.git/
$ echo data > somefile; git add somefile; git commit -m 'first check in'
[master (root-commit) 64a2d9f] first check in
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 somefile
$ echo other > another-file; git add another-file
$ git commit -m 'combine with first check in'
[master d375b81] combine with first check in
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 another-file
$ git rebase -i --root
[in editor, change second line from "pick" to "fixup"; write and quit]
".git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo" 20L, 667C written
[detached HEAD 5b2a979] first check in
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 another-file
 create mode 100644 somefile
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
$ git log --oneline
5b2a979 first check in
```

Note another minor git irritation: `git log` shows commits in new-to-old order, but `git rebase -i` shows them in old-to-new order.

And: if you've `push`ed, the remote has the *old* commits, not the new one.  So you'll see both the old ones, which are reachable via `origin/master` (assuming the remote is named `origin` and you're using the usual setup), and the (single) new one, which is reachable via `master`.  You'll have to get the remote repo to take the new `master`, e.g., via `git push -f` (with all its consequences...).

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've received on SO! One of the serious problems I see with Git is that you have to lower your expectations what the tool supports. Something like what I am trying to do ought to be downright simple, but there are exceptions. You'll smash your head against the wall for hours until you find out that it doesn't support what you're trying to do. I see this as a big failure in that its complexity hides both its usability, bugs and its lack of functionality.

Comment: @user148298: Git can (I find) actually do most of the things one might want it to; it's just that its interface is, well, almost actively "beginner-hostile" in various ways.  For instance, the rebase issue came about because at its core, "rebase" really wants to put new commits *on to* something, so it won't let you "rebase" a root commit which isn't "on" anything, and hence won't let you squash the 2nd commit, which it treats as the 1st.  That's now papered over via `--root` but one shouldn't really *need* `--root`.

Comment: From a technical sense, it makes perfect sense, but from a use case, it unbelievably blindsided. Talk about leaky abstractions!

I run TortoiseGit, Git Gui, VS Git Plugin, Windows Cmd Git Shell, Bash Shell and PowerShell on the same box. Why? So that if I can't find out how to do it on one, I can try to do it on the others. "Beginner" is a misnomer as it hides the fact that some people never get out of the beginner phase. It ought to be called "abused user." Right now, I am trying to find out why Git isn't adding my empty Assets folder and all paths are leading me to lack of support for this.

Comment: Git does indeed have no support for empty directories.  The standard solution is to create a pointless dot-file, such as an empty `.gitignore` file, in the directory.

Comment: Sorry, but I just tried your answer and it doesn't work.  I still see the last two commits.  Boy, this is really frustrating.